# Hyperlinks (of hyperref) linking to invisible bibliography

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I currently have a rather special setup of referenced literature with three non-disjoint bibliographies (two of them visible). In short my question is:

How do I make `\cite`-hyperlinks refer to the last bibliography?

---

If it is of relevance, here are the details of my setup:

- The first visible bibliography references only literature by a certain author.

  - All book references have a prefix-letter.
  - All other references have no prefix. Their reference numbers are in compliance with the literature by other authors.
- The second visible bibliography lists all articles (no books), including some which are not cited in the text.

Here is an MWEB on how it is realized:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, sorting=nyt, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{turingBook2001,
        author = {Turing, Alan},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Title},
        keywords = {b},
    }
    @book{turingBook1999,
        author = {Turing, Alan},
        year = {1999},
        title = {Title},
        keywords = {b},
    }
    @article{turingArticle1970,
        author = {Turing, Alan},
        year = {1970},
        title = {Title},
        keywords = {a},
    }
    @article{turingArticle1950,
        author = {Turing, Alan},
        year = {1950},
        title = {Title},
        keywords = {a},
    }
    @article{hamiltonArticle1969,
        author = {Hamilton, Margaret},
        year = {1969},
        title = {Title},
    }
\end{filecontents}



\begin{document}

This work talks about: \cite{turingBook2001}, \cite{turingBook1999}, \cite{turingArticle1970}, \cite{hamiltonArticle1969}.

% Will not be cited:
\nocite{turingArticle1950}

\section{Publications by Alan Turing}

\defbibnote{book}{Book Chapters}
\defbibnote{article}{Articles}

% Invisible Bibliography, so that article publication reference numbers are alphabetically sorted
\newsavebox\mytempbib
\savebox\mytempbib{\parbox{\textwidth}{\printbibliography[notkeyword=b]}}


\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax  % No new page after each of those bibliographies.

\begin{refcontext}[labelprefix=B]
\printbibliography[heading=none,prenote=book,keyword=b] 
\end{refcontext}
\begin{refcontext}
\printbibliography[heading=none,prenote=article,keyword=a] 
\end{refcontext}


\section{All Articles}
\printbibliography[heading=none,notkeyword=b]
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

It is seen that `\cite{turingBook2001}` and `\cite{turingBook1999}` link to the first visible bibliography, which is wanted behavior.
On the other hand `\cite{turingArticle1970}` and `\cite{hamiltonArticle1969}` link to the invisible bibliography.

How can I have `\cite{turingArticle1970}` and `\cite{hamiltonArticle1969}` link to the last bibliography?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the link `biblatex` uses goes to the first bibliography in which an item occurs. With the following trick you can selectively disable linking for certain bibliography lists by making the command that would set the anchor do nothing. Note that the effect should be kept local (which is the case in the example, but in other settings an explicit `\begingroup...\endgroup` might be needed).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, sorting=nyt, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\disablelink}{\let\blx@anchor\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{turingBook2001,
  author   = {Turing, Alan},
  year     = {2001},
  title    = {Title},
  keywords = {b},
}
@book{turingBook1999,
  author   = {Turing, Alan},
  year     = {1999},
  title    = {Title},
  keywords = {b},
}
@article{turingArticle1970,
  author   = {Turing, Alan},
  year     = {1970},
  title    = {Title},
  keywords = {a},
}
@article{turingArticle1950,
  author   = {Turing, Alan},
  year     = {1950},
  title    = {Title},
  keywords = {a},
}
@article{hamiltonArticle1969,
  author = {Hamilton, Margaret},
  year   = {1969},
  title  = {Title},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This work talks about \cite{turingBook2001,turingBook1999,turingArticle1970,
  hamiltonArticle1969}.

% Will not be cited:
\nocite{turingArticle1950}

\section{Publications by Alan Turing}

\defbibnote{book}{Book Chapters}
\defbibnote{article}{Articles}

% Invisible Bibliography, so that article publication reference numbers are alphabetically sorted
\newsavebox\mytempbib
\savebox\mytempbib{\parbox{\textwidth}{\disablelink\printbibliography[notkeyword=b]}}


\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax  % No new page after each of those bibliographies.

\begin{refcontext}[labelprefix=B]
\printbibliography[heading=none,prenote=book,keyword=b,resetnumbers] 
\end{refcontext}
\begin{refcontext}
\disablelink
\printbibliography[heading=none,prenote=article,keyword=a] 
\end{refcontext}


\section{All Articles}
\printbibliography[heading=none,notkeyword=b]
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image: Turns out you can't see link targets in pictures. So this screenshot of the output is fairly pointless.]

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! And thanks for correcting even the small stuff like my typo :)